# How to reduce load on main thread?

Tags: android

I am pretty new at Android development. I am developing an app which is running slow on opening and the logcat is showing "skipped 55 frames. Too much load on UI thread."I have just heard about async and threading. How can I identify the part in my code that is putting heavy load on main UI. And if you can suggest a way not emphasizing over threading and async tasks.Here what it is doing
`

```
package com.pratham.cricket1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MatchPresetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    int a,b,balls;
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch(adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition()){
            case 0:
                a=0;
                break;
            case 1:
                a=1;
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.match_presets);
        a=0;
        b=0;

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        RadioGroup r1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.choose);


        switch(r1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.t20:
                balls=120;
                break;
            case R.id.t50:
                balls=300;
                break;
        }



    }
    public void toss(View view){
        Random rand=new Random();
        int a=rand.nextInt(50);
        if(a>25){
            b=0;
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Team A wins the toss",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b=1;
            Toast.makeText(this,"Team B wins the toss",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    public void start(View view){
        Intent i1=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("Balls",balls);
        bundle.putInt("Team won toss",b);
        bundle.putInt("Winning team chose",a);
        i1.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i1);

    }
}
```

`
Does the next activity initialising slows it down even though it is not displayed.
This problem is only on Moto g3 and when I try or on opposite phone or works totally fine .

Answer (score 0):

Threading can't be avoided when creating an efficient and responsive application. I suggest you to learn it and not avoid it, since it's an essential part of programming. If you want to identify the part where there is heavy load, check what the application is doing at the time, or write what it is doing and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for advising and as suggested i have included my code for the first activity .